# How to detect uniques and count the number of cells with duplicate data

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of data that has the some of the same values in it. What I want to detect is if that row is unique. If it is, echo 'unique' (or something) but if it's not, count the number of duplicates in the column and echo that number. Example of what I want:

```
COL A     RESULT COLUMN
Apple     Unique
Banana    Unique
Banana    3
Banana    3
Cherry    Unique
Date      Unique
Date      2
```

Example of what I have using this code (`=IF(A1=A2, "Duplicate", "Unique")`):

```
COL A     RESULT COLUMN
Apple     Unique
Banana    Unique
Banana    DUPLICATE
Banana    DUPLICATE
Cherry    Unique
Date      Unique
Date      DUPLICATE
```

I guess what I really need is a query inserted(?) into where the 'Duplicate' text is in that formula that will count down the same cell values until it sees a different value, and echo that number.

If it can be done within the same column excellent. If I need another column and have to perform two sets of queries I can compromise.

**UPDATE BASED ON DATATOO ANSWER**

I ran that query, modified column 'A' to 'E' and this is what returned.

```
City Country Merge  Duplicate City Country
Aberdeen, UK    Unique
Aberdeen, UK    2
Bangor, UK          2
Bath, UK            Unique
Belfast, UK         Unique
Birmingham, UK  Unique
Birmingham, UK  Unique
Birmingham, UK  Unique
Birmingham, UK  Unique
Birmingham, UK  Unique
Birmingham, UK  Unique
Birmingham, UK  Unique
Birmingham, UK  Unique
```

As you can see this doesn't count right. Thoughts?

Comment: do you want the first instance of a row to display "unique" as in your example, or do you want only unique rows to display that? for instance banana is not truly unique a unique row

Comment: I know banana is not truly a unique row as there are multiple other rows containing banana, however I do want the first instace of banana to display as unique.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I see that it was never satisfactorily answered, so I hope this is still useful.

You want this:

```
=if(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)=1, "UNIQUE", COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A1))
```

This will fill down and look like this in subsequent rows:

```
=if(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)=1, "UNIQUE", COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A2))
=if(COUNTIF($A$1:$A3,A3)=1, "UNIQUE", COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A3))
...
```

And these are the results (assuming the formula was inserted into B1 and filled down):

```
    A         B
1 Apple     UNIQUE
2 Banana    UNIQUE
3 Banana    3
4 Banana    3
5 Cherry    UNIQUE
6 Date      UNIQUE
7 Date      2
```

The key to your problem is that you're looking for the first occurrence of the string to count as unique, *then* you count the duplicates. So, for the first part of the formula, you're really only searching the list so far, not the entire list.

This method also has the added advantage of working with an unsorted list as well as a sorted one.

Comment: Thanks. It is an old question for an old project, but this answer is perfect. Hopefully it will help someone else. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Duotrigesimal, could I use a version of this for my issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843406/mark-duplicate-entries-in-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 2):

I know your example shows banana as unique, and you may be asking for the first instance of a row to display that way, but if not.....

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A1)=1,"Unique",COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A1))
```

apologies if you truly intend the first row of an item to show as unique

Comment: Hey Datatoo, thanks for this but yes I do intend to show the first row as 'unique'.

Also, this doesn't seem to work exactly. My actual column is column E, so I replaced all instances of 'A' with 'E' -- that right?

Have updated question above with results on this solution. Needs more adjusting. Thanks for helping on this.

Comment: The error with the counts being wrong is likely caused by spaces in the string, so "Birmingham, UK" is different than "Birmingham, UK " which means you might add Trim to the mix. May we see an actual copy of the formula that you are now using which supplies the first "Unique" also? Or perhaps I am misunderstanding your cell columns

Comment: @davebowker Column E is the City? from your example it is hard to tell. How are you using Merge and Duplicate?

Comment: Here's a link to a section of the actual dataset. https://spreadsheets.google.com/a/davebowker.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AnaEFTwUq7nedHIxOXdubmt3WVVMb2gwRVh0UTVubUE&single=true&gid=7&range=A1%3AH10&output=html

Comment: And... here's my formulas 
=CONCATENATE(C2,", ",D2) --- this makes column E
=IF(E1=E2, "Duplicate", "Unique") -- this checks the cell against the cell above to see if it's a unique or a duplicate.

In my mind, I need to replace where it says 'Duplicate' above to count just how many duplicates there are?

Again, thanks for helping with this.

Comment: If your "City, Country" Is always sorted so that you can depend upon looking at the previous cell, you can use the Unique/Duplicate formula you are using. You can then also append the counts =CONCATENATE(C2,", ",D2)&" "&COUNTIF($E$2:$E$100,E2)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't need the concatenate so I've removed that, and now have this: =COUNTIF($E$2:$E$100,E2)

I then did a fill down using this code and it worked pretty much perfectly, counting instances of country and printing the number. However as soon as it hit row 120, everything afterwards printed '0'

Any ideas why? Is there a row limit to this formula?

Comment: you have to expand the countif range beyond $E$100 for sure, and sometimes if there is a difference in the string it is counting and the cell it is comparing to you will have that. For instance, "Birmingham, UK" and "Birmingham  ,UK" would not be the same (even my example here in the comment strips spaces, but your cell may not, so trim the strings

Comment: Not a 100% on how to use TRIM. Have looked at the doc and can get it to work on its own, but not sure how to combine it with the unique count code.

Comment: Actually, I am sorry, you would have to Trim() on each cell in the range. And that might require an added column temporarily that you paste back over. You want to eliminate unnecessary spaces, and compare to the same spellins. But makle sure you have also extended the compare range to encompass everything you ar counting instances in