# Mark Duplicate Entries in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with entries in column F that could be duplicates later on in F. I'm looking to make something that does something like this pseudocode:

`While Ax is not empty`

```
If value in Gx is empty   
  If cell Ex is identical to other cell Ey
  OR 
  If cell Fx is identical to other cell Fy 
     THEN
       Mark Gy as duplicate
       italics row y
```

Any recommendations on making this work using Google's built in app scripting?

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with JS but I'm trying.

Comment: Can you post example data with the expected output? That might help clarify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: How would you recommend I share it? I don't see a way to embed a spreadsheet in here.. I'll try to make a public spreadsheet with example content.

Comment: Here we go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AitVDLyAs3jUdDQtVGdxdWRfUnNkcWZmRlItRXF1d1E&usp=sharing

Comment: So the idea would be that if the Contact is identical OR if the Name is identical, then mark as Duplicate.

Comment: There's no need to embed or link anything. Just copy the relevant information into your question like I did in my answer. Keep that in mind for your next question. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: if you need to just know what the dups are instead of marking them, use this formula http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82278/how-can-i-find-duplicates-in-a-column-using-formulas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need JS for this. You can do it with the built-in spreadsheet formulas.

It sounds like you want a similar answer that I gave to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755544/how-to-detect-uniques-and-count-the-number-of-cells-with-duplicate-data-in-googl/14299914#comment29509864_14299914), with the difference being that you are checking two columns instead of just one.

You want this:

```
=if(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)=1, COUNTIF($B$1:$B2,B2)=1), "", "Yes")
```

The key thing to notice is the use of the [`AND`](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en) forumla.

This will fill down and look like this in subsequent rows:

```
=if(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A3,A3)=1, COUNTIF($B$1:$B3,B3)=1), "", "Yes")
=if(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A4,A4)=1, COUNTIF($B$1:$B4,B4)=1), "", "Yes")
...
```

And these are the results using your spreadsheet data as an example. This is assuming the formula was inserted into the `Duplicate?` column (C2) and filled down:

```
   A                          B               C
1  Contact                    Name            Duplicate?
2  email@example.com          John  
3  repeat.email@example.com   Repeated Name 
4  repeat.email@example.com   Jane            Yes
5  email3@example.com         Repeated Name   Yes
```

Comment: Q: What do the '$' in front of A, 1 & A4 do for the formula?

Comment: Never mind, I Just found this: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/googlespreadsheets/14.3

Comment: But oddly enough, these '$' references don't result in expected results when referring to data in another spreadsheet with '!' I can't get this formula to run with secondary references, but can with this: `=if(OR(COUNTIF('Sheet2'!G1:G5,G4), COUNTIF('Sheet2'!H1:H300,G4), ""), "Duplicate", "Still Unique")`

Comment: Google's syntax has changed, here's the updated version:

`=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2;A2)=1; COUNTIF($B$1:$B2;B2)=1); ""; "Yes")`