# Counting row duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with approximately 10,000 rows with three columns: colA, colB and colC. Data looks something like this:

```
colA, ColB, ColC
a,b,c
a,x,y
d,e,f
d,t,g
d,y,g
```

colA contains a value which will appear in one or more colA cells.  What I want is to add a fourth column (sumCol) which will be a numerical representation of the number of times the value in colA has been replicated in other rows.  So my new data set would look like

```
colA, ColB, ColC, sumCol
a,b,c,2
a,x,y,2
d,e,f,3
d,t,g,3
d,y,g,3
```

i.e. `2` in sumCol as 'a' has appeared twice, `3` as 'd' has appeared thrice.

What is the best way to do this?

I have read up on pivot tables but I'm not sure if this is way to go.  This is the closest I have got on SO for a similar question but it's not really the same as I am trying to do [How to detect uniques and count the number of cells with duplicate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755544/how-to-detect-uniques-and-count-the-number-of-cells-with-duplicate-data-in-googl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you want is

```
COUNTIF(A$1:A$5,"="&$A1)
```

assuming that cell `A1` contains the first value in `colA`.